# Three Divs Side By Side on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make it so that when the mouse is hovered over one div, the whole row highlights and allows the user to click it? I am totally confused about whether to use Javascript or Jquery.

Here is a link to a preview and viewing of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cMpaE/

By the way, I am using these as listview type of control, so there will be multiple of these on one page.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

Wrap the row in a container div, then toggle a class whenever you enter / leave the div

Css:

```
.hover > div {
    background-color: #0f0 !important; /* Only need !important to override your inline css */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#logoBlock,#promotionBlock,#descriptionBlock').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});
```

See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/m22Gu/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the useful jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

First create a css class called `highlight` that represents the style you want to show on the div, and all the other divs in that row of the listbox when hovered.

Then, on each div that's generated, identify which row of your listbox it's on with a data attribute, and give it a corresponding css class:

```
<div data-rownum="2" class="row2" ...
```

Then

```
$("div[class *= 'row']").hover(function() {
    $(".row" + $(this).data("rownum")).addClass("highlight");
}, function() {
    $(".row" + $(this).data("rownum")).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

---

For the second part of your question, the user will only be able to click on a div when the mouse is over it, right?  So just attach a click handler to your rows' divs,

```
$(document).on("click", "div[class *= 'row']", function() {
    //click handler
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have to do some reading on ID's in CSS now :)

Comment: I've been looking around and I can't seem to find any understandable explanations for what you've just said about assigning data rownums to a div. I really need some way to assign each div (as you've shown above) an ID according to the MYSQL ID from my database so that when the user clicks on the listview, I can bring up related content according to the ID.

Comment: @tushar747 - it's something you'd have to do yourself, but I think jhof's answer is better anyway